# Passport expiration with layover

Tags: transit, passports, sweden

I'm going to Ireland the last week of April and they do not have a minimum passport validity but I have a layover in Sweden which has a 6 month minimum passport validity requirement.  My passport expires in August.  Should I renew now or will I be ok?

**Edit:** My longest layover is about 3 hours so i didn't plan on leaving the airport.

Comment: Are you clearing immigration in Sweden?

Comment: Call your embassy in Sweden. They might be able to help you with a fresh validity passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes renew now because although you do not plan on exiting the airport, sometimes things happen beyond your control and you are forced to exit the airport. It has happened to people many times including [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89937/does-heathrow-terminal-5-allow-transit-visa-exempt-flyers-to-stay-airside-overni/89947#89947). Your question implies you do have the option to renew, exercise it now and eliminate the risk, however minuscule.

How much do you save by waiting till five months before renewing? If you have a passport normally valid for 10 years, that's less than 5% savings. For a $80 passport, that is $4 of savings. Is it worth getting denied boarding, or any conceivable hassle etc? The numbers I use are only assumptions however you get the idea, its not worth waiting.

Comment: Very good point, thanks.  In the mail and expedited, hopefully it all goes thru without issue and i have it in 2 weeks.