# Do I need a transit visa for a 17 hour layover in London?

Tags: uk, canada, india, london

I want to book a flight from Canada to India that has two layovers, one in Helsinki and one in London. The layover in London is 17 hours and extends into the day after I arrive. I don't intend to leave the airport. I checked the transit visa requirements and it said I 'may' be eligible to travel without a visa since I have a Canadian and USA visa. I wanted to get confirmation on the same

Comment: Check the linked answer and also note that you *may* be required to pass through border control for an overnight stay, [see this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/89947/28009). And in that case, you won't be eligible for transit without visa. Therefore, the safest option will be to apply for for a visitor in transit visa.

Comment: @MJeffryes the statement "[in case you have to pass through border control], you won't be eligible for transit without visa" is [incorrect](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/yes).

Comment: @phoog Yes I know that's true in the general case, but my understanding is that transiting without a visa and crossing border control is only allowed if your flight arrives and departs on the same day. Since we know this isn't the case for OP, transiting without visa would only be possible if they can stay airside.

Comment: @phoog ie, if you change the answer "will you pass through UK border control" to no on the visa tool you linked, there's no longer a requirement that you arrive and depart on the same day https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/somewhere_else/no

Comment: @MJeffryes the requirement is that you depart on the same day as arrival *or the day after,* which is the case here ("You might be eligible for ‘transit without visa’ if you ... have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive *or before midnight on the day after you arrive*...."; emphasis added).